# Modify Future[JsArray] in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I use the Play 2.0 framework for getting data from my MongoDB.

This is done by the following code:

```
def getTopicsInAppFormat = Action.async {
// let's do our query
val cursor: Cursor[TopicModel] = topicCollection.find(Json.obj()).cursor[TopicModel]

// gather all the JsObjects in a list
val futureTopicsList: Future[List[TopicModel]] = cursor.collect[List]()

// transform the list into a JsArray
val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] = futureTopicsList.map { topics =>
  Json.arr(topics)
}

// everything's ok! Let's reply with the array
futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
  topics =>
    Ok(topics(0))
}
}
```

But the problem is that I want the function to return an alternative representation of the data. So, I want for example to change the amount of attributes, etc. What is a good way to achieve that? I tried to modify the data (respectively create a new array with the new format) in the last step, right before the Ok() function. However, I didn't have any progress with that :/

EDIT:
At the moment I'm trying to create new JSON objects but I'm stuck while getting the data from the original one...
My current code looks like this:

```
futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
  topics =>

    /* Access a attribute */
    println(topics(0).\("content"))
    /* However: error: JsUndefined('content' is undefined on object */

    /* Could be used to set the new attributes */
    val myNewJson = Json.obj(
      "name" -> "JohnDoe",
      "age" -> "123",
      "created" -> new java.util.Date().getTime())

    Ok(/*topics(0)*/myNewJson)
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I updated the topic accordingly.

Comment: It looks like you're just misinterpretting the format of `topics`.  If you provide the JSON value of `topics` it would help a lot!

Comment: ahh, thank you @BenReich! I can access the value by using .\\ instead of .\ ... Okay, now the remaining part shouldn't be that hard ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably misinterpreting the format of `topics`.  The message you're getting is telling you that there is no `content` property on the first element of the `topics` array.  This is a simplified example:

```
val myObject = Json.obj("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
myObject \ "a" //JsNumber(1)
myObject \ "c" //JsUndefined('c' is undefined on object...)
```

This makes sense, since we get `undefined` in Javascript when trying to read a property that doesn't exist.  In the Play Json library, `\` always returns a `JsValue`, and one of its subtypes is `JsUndefined`.

You should reexamine the format of the objects in the `topics` array and reassess how you can access its values.

Answer (score 0):

Now, my final solution for the problem "modify the data just before returning" looks like this:

```
futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
  topics =>

    def createNewFormat(uID: JsValue, name: JsValue, content: JsValue, lat: JsValue, lng: JsValue): JsObject = {
      return Json.obj(
        "id" -> uID,
        [...]
    }

    /* Access the needed attributes */
    val uIDs    = topics(0).\\("uID")
    val names   = topics(0).\\("name")
    val content = topics(0).\\("content")
    val gps     = topics(0).\\("gps")

    var dataArray = new JsArray()

    /* create new Array */
    for( i <- 0 to uIDs.length-1){
      dataArray = dataArray.append(createNewFormat(uIDs(i),names(i),content(i),gps(i)(0),gps(i)(1)))
    }

    /* put this into a new JSObject */
    var returnThis = Json.obj("data" -> dataArray)

    Ok(returnThis)
}
```

Maybe this does help someone with similar problems :)